# What is the usual workflow among a user, a smart contract and an oracle?

Tags: blockchain, oracles

Suppose a user *A* wants to feed a certain smart contract *F* with some data *d* that can be obtained from an oracle *O*.

What is the usual workflow in the most popular oracle solutions?

I imagine two possible scenarios:

1. *A* sends a request to a smart contract monitored by *O* (and a certain fee for example) specifying that *d* has to be sent to *F*, then *O* writes *d* directly on *F*.
2. As an alternative, *O* may send *d* to *A*, then *A* sends *d* to *F* and *F* verifies some signature proving that *d* is actually coming from *O*.

Answer (score 0):

A call a function in the smart contract F, which sends a request to a smart contract monitored by O (and a certain fee for example). O send d to F using a callback function, and F deal with the information.
Or F send a query to O directly...

Oracles can have different approaches, take a look on this article:
[Types of Blockchain Oracles](https://chain.link/education/blockchain-oracles#types-of-blockchain-oracles)